# value of checkbox to database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Been trying to get the values ​​of the checkbox in to the database but failed, 
anyone have tips on how I can get the values ​​of the checkbox in to my datbasen?

Then a question, how can I run post action in the same file?

My code so long:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("db_info");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO mass (gift, name, epost, interest) 
VALUES 
('$_POST[gift_nor]','$_POST[name_nor]','$_POST[epost_nor]','$_POST[interest_nor]')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>


<form method="post" action="">

    <input type="radio" name="gift_nor" value="present_1">present_1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gift_nor" value="present_2">present_2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gift_nor" value="present_3">present_3

    <hr />

    Namn: <input type="text" name="name_nor">
    Epostadress: <input type="text" name="epost_nor">

    <hr />

    <input type="checkbox" name="interest_nor[]" value="int_1">I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest_nor[]" value="int_2">I have a car<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest_nor[]" value="int_3">I have a computer

    <hr />        

    <input name="Send" type="submit" id="Skicka">
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting checkbox values into MySQL Database with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142860/inserting-checkbox-values-into-mysql-database-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

use `implode`, 
do something like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Send']))
{
$con=mysqli_connect("db_info");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $check=implode(',', $_POST['interest_nor']); //it convert checkbox array into string

    $sql="INSERT INTO mass (gift, name, epost, interest) 
    VALUES 
    ('$_POST[gift_nor]','$_POST[name_nor]','$_POST[epost_nor]','$check')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: It saves the values ​​in the database now, but may be this error when I visit the page where the form are: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /storage/content/67/130567/s10.se/public_html/db.php on line 18

Comment: tried what you wrote last, but when no value is sent to the database.

Comment: I copied what you wrote in the box above (the entire php code).

Have I missed something?

As I did so, nothing happens.

Comment: I have copied exactly what you typed in full. But now sends it does not collect any data to the database.